# Point values not being handled correctly

Tags: python, point, dimension

I have a PointND class representing a point in N-dimensional space (shown below).

```
class PointND:
    """
    Class to represent an N-dimensional point.
    """
    def __init__(self, *vals):
        if len(vals) == 1 and isinstance(vals, list):
            self.vals = vals[0]
        else:
            self.vals = vals
        self.point = []
        self.dimensions = len(self.vals)
        for i in self.vals:
            self.point.append(i)
```

This works fine when I give it a series of inputs (ex: `PointND(1, 2, 3, 4)`). However, whenever I give it a list of inputs (ex: `PointND([1, 2, 3, 4])`) it breaks.

I have the `__repr__` function defined as:

```
def __repr__(self):
        __a = f"{self.dimensions}D Point: ({self.vals[0]}"
        for i in range(1, len(self.vals)):
            __a = f"{__a}, {self.vals[i]}"
        __a = f"{__a})"
        return __a
```

And when I do `print(PointND(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`, it outputs:

```
> 4D Point: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

However when I simply change it to: `print(PointND([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))`, it outputs:

```
> 1D Point: ([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I don't know why it does this, but if anyone knows and/or has a fix, please let me know!

Comment: It "breaks" because `*args` means a list of comma separated values passed as arguments, but `vals` itself is a list that wraps these arguments.
If you pass a list, then `vals` will be a list of your arguments, so a list of list.

Comment: Sorry but I just realized why it broke. Instead of checking if only one input was given and that the first, and only, input was a list, I checked if *vals itself was a list. Programming is very fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you probably meant to check the type of `vals[0]`, not `vals`.

```
    def __init__(self, *vals):
-       if len(vals) == 1 and isinstance(vals, list):
+       if len(vals) == 1 and isinstance(vals[0], list):
            self.vals = vals[0]
        else:
            self.vals = vals
```

(`vals` will never be a list, it will always be a tuple)

I would argue that this is a bad interface: it lets you express the same thing in two different ways. I would pick one way of creating a point:

```py
# a) accept varargs
    def __init__(self, *vals):
        self.point = list(vals)
        self.dimensions = len(vals)

# b) accept a list (or any iterable, really)
    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.point = list(vals)
        self.dimensions = len(vals)
```

Comment: Yes, as stated in my above comment, I mistyped and forgot about it.